# Is there a way to play a wav file so that it is not locally dependent when i make the program an exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am wondering if there is a way to play an audio file without needing to have it locally when the project is exported to an exe file. There is a way to do it in c# (.net), so i reckon there is also a way to do this in python. I am using pyinstaller to export the file to an exe.

Comment: You mean you want to *bundle* the sound file into the EXE file?

Comment: Yes, i think that is the correct terminology.